# How to get actual class type from Class<T> method argument

Tags: java, spring, generics

I am trying to get the instance or class name from the method argument as follows :

```
public class Test {

   public void getData (Class<T> type){
     // Class type of instance of "type" method argument.
      if(type instanceOf SomeClass) {
        //Do something
      }
   }
}
```

I have already tried reflation methods like getClass(), getSimpleClassName(), getName() etc. These all are returning class name as "Class" and instance as "class java.lang.Class". I need it to compare the instance with some class and do necessary operation.

Comment: `type == SomeClass.class`

Comment: Why are you needing this information? Could this be an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask how to solve a specific code problem when the best solution is to use a completely different approach.

Comment: `type instanceOf SomeClass` won't work with classes, try `SomeClass.class.isAssignableFrom( type )` instead. But as Hovercraft suggested you should take one step back and think about whether you really need that or whether there's a better (read easier to understand and maintain, less fragile etc.) solution.

Comment: type.equals(SomeClass.class) , this worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the types should be exactly the same (equals for example String.class and String.class then you can use == or equals)

```
public class Test {

   public void getData (Class<T> type){
     // Class type of instance of "type" method argument.
      if(type.equals(SomeClass.class) {
        //Do something
      }
   }
}
```

ELse if the types are related by inheritance e.g CharSequence.class and String.class you can use assignableFrom

```
public class Test {

   public void getData (Class<T> type){
     // Class type of instance of "type" method argument.
      if(SomeClass.class.isAssignableFrom(type) {
        //Do something
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just do `type == SomeClass.class`, however I find your code somewhat *smelly*.

I would do:

1. Introduce a generic interface `Abstract<T>` with an abstract `public void getData()` method.

For example:

```
public interface Abstract<T> {
    public void getData();
}
```

2. For each *valid* type parameter for `T` (feel free to limit it with some bound), I would create a subclass, where the implementation of the `getData()` method would be just the behavior of the corresponding `if` block in your code:

For example:

```
public class SomeClassSpecific implements Abstract<SomeClass> {
    public void getData() {
        //specific implementation for SomeClass. 
    }
}
```

This way you'll end up with a bunch of small, easy-testable and clean classes, the implementation of which would cover the whole `if-else` body of your `getData(Class<T> clazz)` method.

Answer (score -2):

You need to just use the typeof function .

```
Type t=typeof(T);
```

Thanks .

Comment: typeof isn't a java function ... instanceof is what you probably mean